# Variable in node.js JavaScript doesn't change

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function simpleTest() {
    var content = '';
    http.get("http://google.com/", function (res) {
        var html = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            html += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            content = html;
        });
    });
    return content;
}

console.log(simpleTest());
```

Why variable doesn't change and I get an empty string?

I think that the first function displays variable, and only then execute the `http.get`. How to make the first code executed and only then the function returns a variable?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: content is return before it is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the operation is asynchronous. This means that `simpleTest` returns long before the `http.get()` response arrives.

Any code that needs the response must be invoked from in the callback. In your case, there could be multiple invocations of the `data` callback, so you need to handle it inside the `end` callback.

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function simpleTest() {
    http.get("http://google.com/", function (res) {
        var html = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            html += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log(html);
        });
     });
}

simpleTest();
```

---

If you don't want to hardcode the `console.log()`, you can put it in a function, and pass the function to `simpleTest()`. This makes it much more generic.

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function simpleTest(fn) {
    http.get("http://google.com/", function (res) {
        var html = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            html += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            fn(html);
        });
     });
}

simpleTest(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

So here we passed a function to the `fn` parameter, and invoked the `fn` parameter inside the `end` callback.

When we invoke it, we pass the final `html` value, and the callback receives it in its `data` parameter.

These are very common patterns, so it would be a good idea to get familiar with them.